# Forwarding-service for emails on external hoster by MX-record

Tags: email, mx-record, forwarding

I am registering domains on behalf of customers and host their websites on my server.

**I have complete control over the DNS setup of my customer domains. I still want to host their websites, but I don't want to be responsible for their emails**

Now they need forwarding of some emails of their domains to existing mail accounts on other hosters (hotmail, gmail, etc.).

**What I need is the following:**
I would set the MX-record to a provider, where I can configure forwarding rules for the emails of my customers.

Would a service provider charge you for that kind of forwarding-service? There would be no storage needed at that provider, only some throughgoing traffic from the forwarded emails.

Comment: You may want to check the the at registrar. Some of them provide this feature at no extra charge.  Gmail also supports this but could be time-consuming setup if you have a lot of accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most reputable e-mail hosting providers would allow all e-mails to be forwarded from an account to another account as well.  Since most reputable email hosts charge for service its safe to assume that this type of functionality is included in the account setup.

Essentially you would setup an "account" on the new host and then forward that traffic to whatever back-end address you want it to go to.  Each host has different control panels for setting this up however.

At the most basic level you could probably setup Google Apps or Office 365 for your clients to do e-mail hosting and other productivity enhancements which could provide a huge value-add for your customers.  Office 365 can even be resold by you and billed monthly so it appears as part of the overall service you are providing to them.

Comment: I started with Google Apps, and it seems to work fine for 10 users and it's free. I can add my domain there and prove that it belongs to me with an html-file from google. Then I can set the MX-record pointing to the google server and define an email-forwarding there then in GMail

Comment: You can also use a simple TXT record from Google to prove ownership as well.  I also highly recommend looking into SPF and DKIM as spam prevention mechanisms.

Comment: The Google service works, but it is a pity that Google would be able to read and archive all emails if I would use that service. My customers don't like that, so I cannot use Google or Microsoft for such a service. They want privacy

Comment: Then you fail to understand how any e-mail provider and system truly work. The company does not actively allow employees to read e-mail, instead the scan the content electronically to improve searches and other features that are built in. Any e-mail system worth its weight does the same type of thing. If your customer really valued their privacy they would run their own e-mail service and not let you control it either.

Comment: Isn't there a service provider out there, that doesn't scan your emails like Google & Co?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the provider, its the server software that does it by default. Most mail server programs read every e-mail that comes through the system.  This is typically required for several required services like SPAM prevention.  The content has to be evaluated every time a message is sent or received to make sure the content meets policy requirements, etc. So no, there is not really any client out there that does not scan or process the message content.

Comment: Scanning for spam and viruses is OK. But scanning to analyse the content (like Google does) is not very welcome. Maybe there exists a trustworthy provider out there? Where the content of your emails is not logged for advertisement and profiling purposes?

Answer (score 0):

It would take:

- You to add some MX records for the domains, pointing to servers which will handle the email
- Servers configured to accept email for the domains
- Whatever configuration you need to relay email to the final destination addresses. This could be as simple as a catch-all sending all email to one address, but if you need "enquiries@" to go to three people and "info@" to go to two people, etc. then it's pretty much a full email system.

Yes, a service provider would typically charge for this kind of thing. Rollernet.us does this kind of email relay service, for example.